# HTML & CSS - Shortcut URL

Tags: html, css, url, hyperlink, shortcut

I wonder how to make shortcut URL in html and css (if it is possible)

I mean this:

```
 HTML   <a href="#URL1">URL1</a>

 CSS    #URL1 { URL('nextpage.html');}
```

Is this somehow possible?
Thank you for your answers.

So it can't work like this?

```
var url1 = "http://www.google.com"; 

<a href="url1">Google</a>
```

Is there any option how to do it?

Comment: you want variable for url?you should use sass

Comment: Is there any option to make it only with html and css?

Comment: No, that's not possible, @PepaGazdoš.

Answer (score 2):

To give you the short answer, **no, you can't achieve this only by using CSS and HTML.**

**Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)** is a style sheet language used for describing the look and formatting of a document written in a markup language. While most often used to change the style of web pages and user interfaces written in HTML and XHTML, the language can be applied to any kind of XML document, including plain XML, SVG and XUL. ([...read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets))

Also, here is an **[introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)** to what CSS is and how to use it.

I recommend you also take a look at [**HTML Links**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

### To not be all negative, I will give you some solutions, you could use `.attr` and do it like this :

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#firstlink').attr("href", "http://google.com")
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="firstlink">This will take you to google</a>
```

---

### *...or you could do it like this:*

**SCRIPT**

```
var url = document.getElementById("firstlink")
url.setAttribute("href", "http://google.com")
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="firstlink">This will take you to google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be possible. As css is for only styling the html.
Yes you can target particular url to style it.
Check out [**this**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) page for further detail.

Comment: There's no reason to do it that way,unless you need a variable for url then do as mentioned above,use sass

Answer (score -1):

Or you can do it with php.

```
<?php
$url = 'example.com' ;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" >
click here 
</a>
```

Comment: Is it really worth using php only to add some links ?

Comment: @Alin I'm not telling that use php for only this purpose but giving the only idea that you can achieve this by php.